# php mb_detect_encoding equivalent in mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have a process in php like...

```
if (mb_detect_encoding($msg) == 'ASCII') {
....
} else  {
....
}
```

Now, the above functionality I have to enable in mysql procedure. Is there any function or work around to achieve in mysql.

In other simple word mb_detect_encoding() equivalent in mysql !

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just do everything as utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in mysql and I'm not even sure that you should have such functionality in  adatabase either. Columns storing text have their fixed character set in mysql. It is the responsibility of the application using the database to ensure that text with right encoding is entered into the database.

EDIT:

Obviously, nothing prevents you from implementing a similar functionality using UDFs if you really insist on having this functionality within mysql.